# JSP Tag Library and xhtml

Tags: jsf, richfaces, jsp-tags

I trying to create a custom tag the Java way, by extending `TagSupport`. I'm want to use the custom tag to render some html in a xhtml file which also used RichFaces and JSF.

All the tutorials I've seen regarding custom tags you register then in a `jsp` page via:

```
 <% taglib prefix="example" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tag-descriptor.tld" %>
```

However this does not work in xhtml documents. I've seen the custom xhtml tags based on xhtml snippets, but I really need logic in the code.

So how do you register a jsp tag lib in jsf? Is this possible? And if not, is there anyway to script java in a xhtml page as you do with jsp?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a Facelet (.xhtml) you can't register a JSP tag lib.

Facelets is a completely different technology than JSP and those two are not compatible in any way where it concerns artifacts that are specific to each technology (like `javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.TagSupport`).

However, what's behind a custom JSP tag for JSF is a component, and you can of course author these in Java for Facelets. It boils down to creating a component directly in Java and then registering this in a `*-taglib.xml` (for JSF 2.2, this registration in an XML file won't be needed anymore).

See [Simple Java based JSF custom component](http://jdevelopment.nl/simple-java-based-jsf-custom-component) for more info.

Comment: Why are you disappointed? The tag in JSP is only a wrapper around a component anyway. The tag support class only delegates parameters (values and expressions) to the component. If you need something that is not component centric in nature, then Facelets does offer you tag handlers. See e.g. http://jdevelopment.nl/passing-action-methods-facelets-tags and http://weblogs.java.net/blog/edburns/archive/2009/10/15/jsf2-facelet-tag-handlers